# Flutter says Execution failed for task ':sqflite:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, sqflite

I used to have this sqflite in my pubspec.yaml file but recently I removed the dependence seeing I won't be making use of it, then I run the app on my android device and emulator I got a strange error and have googled for the solution, it seems I can't find any help and as well check stackoverflow.

**What have done so far:**

1. As a rule of thumb, i ran `flutter clean` to see if issue will be
   resolved but it did not worked either
2. Invalidate and Restart Android Studio

**Here is the Error am having**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/Users/zionnite/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-2.0.0+3/android/src/main/java/com/tekartik/sqflite/SqflitePlugin.java:910: error: cannot find symbol
                        database.deleteDatabase(path);
                        ^
  symbol: variable database
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sqflite:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 58s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**Dependency of Interest**

```
#  sqflite: ^2.0.0+3
#  path_provider: ^2.0.1
```

At this time even if I enable the dependency, the issue still persists.

However, everything is working out great on my ios simulator except android device and emulator

Comment: Please anyone with a solution to this?, I had to uninstall my app to see if issue will be resolved but it did not

Comment: Same issue for me, upgrade  my gradle to gradle:7.0.0' and my gradle wrapper to /gradle-7.0.2-all.zip worked for me.

Comment: check the second answer

Answer (score 1):

The issue caused by Java version 8. So you should use **Java version 11.**

- Add this to build.gradle file (android/app/build.gradle)

  ```
   compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
  ```
- Change JDK of Gradle in Android studio
  [image]

Finally, Clean and rebuild.
That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved after downloading Java 11,also check the gradle and wrapper version you're using

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering the same issue.I have done everything which is mentioned on stackoverflow .but the problem is in my new added package which is cached_network_image .I just remove this package and every thing start working.So you just check which new package you added and which create fuss..

Answer (score 0):

I was able combat the enemy of death fighting for the progress of my code and obtain victory through the magical touch of `flutter pub cache repair`.

what i mean to say is that, when i ran `flutter pub cache repair`, Flutter was able to build and run on my android device and emulator