# flutter build failed Execution failed for task ':sqflite:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, sqflite

flutter build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':sqflite:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

flutter version 3.3.6

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3"

thanks

Comment: It may answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67328948/flutter-says-execution-failed-for-task-sqflitecompiledebugjavawithjavac

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

and

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1'
```